# How to detect checkbox is true using ng-checked?

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to make a user picker which allows you to pick multiple people.  I am trying to make it so the user clicks on the div and then an icon would appear on the div and the checkbox itself would be hidden.  I have currently got it working for when the user clicks on the checkbox and am now trying to make it work for when they click on the div instead.  But currently when the user clicks on the containing div, the box checks but there is no action resulting from it. It still works when you click on the checkbox though. Can anyone help me to understand what is going on here?

My code looks like this:

```
this.users = [
{name: Arnold, $id: simplelogin:1},
{name: Bob, $id: simplelogin:2},
{name: Chris, $id: simplelogin:3}];

$scope.selectedUsers = function selectedUsers(){
    console.log("selected users: ", $scope.selectedUsers);
    return filterFilter($scope.user, {selected: true});
};

$scope.$watch('todo.groupUsers|filter:{selected:true}', function(nv){
    todos.selectionIds = nv.map(function(user){
        return user.$id;
    });
}, true);
```

html:

```
<div ng-repeat="user in todo.groupUsers">
<div class="userBar" ng-model="todo.addTask.user" ng-class="user.color"  ng-click="selectUser = !selectUser">
    <span ng-show="selectUser" class="icon-tick2_Tick2 left"></span>
    <input ng-checked="selectUser"  class="hidden" type="checkbox" ng-model="user.selected">
    <span  class="userName" >{{user.name}}</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue and solved it by software clicking. Here's an example

```
scope.clickOnSomeElement = function ($event) {
    $event.stopPropagation();
    $timeout(function() {
        angular.element('#desired-element').trigger('click');
    }, 0);
};
```